# Find and Replace rich text without losing formatting

Tags: vb.net

I’m new to programming and need some help.

I’m using VB 2010 express and I’m trying to read a .rtf file to a string, then find and replace text within it and finally output as a new file

I’ve managed to do this with the below code, BUT it loses the formatting the carriage return and the output is all on one line?

thanks for any help
James

```
Private Sub Button16_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button16.Click

    Dim fileReader As String
    fileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Testing\Reports\test2.rtf")

    fileReader = fileReader.Replace("@@HCO@@", RichTextBox1.Text)

    Dim StreamW As New IO.StreamWriter("C:\Testing\Reports\test3.rtf")

    StreamW.Write(fileReader)
    StreamW.Close()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
RichTextBox1.Text
```

doesnt hold the formatting information. try instead:

```
RichTextBox1.Rtf
```

also the ReadAlltext function removes the cr you are missing. try ReadToEnd instead

Comment: thanks for the help, I tried RichTextBox1.SelectedRtf which worked if all text is selected, then stumbled across RichTextBox1.Rtf this works without selecting the text. Do you know what I could use if I replaced the RichTextBox with a TextBox?

Comment: i dont feel like i get what you wanna do. as far as i know the syntax of rtf you can replace text without damaging the existing formatting. otherwise you have to add the formatting yourself. i googled and found this: http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm

if this doesn't help you - please give me a more detailed info what you wanna do.